# Displaying text in static text field in mfc dialog

Tags: c++, mfc

I built a game in MFC, and I want to display the score user got in static text field of dialog, so I want to do something something like this:

```
staticScore.SetWindowText(_T("you got %d points", score));
```

But this doens't work, this displays "you got %d points" without replacing %d with score.

How can I display number that is stored in some variable in static text field?

Comment: Format first, pass to `SetWindowText` second.

Answer (score 1):

```
CString score;
score.Format(_T("You got %d points"),m_score);
staticScore.SetWindowText(score);
```